# Paternity testing using gel electrophoresis

Tags: homework, gel-electrophoresis

When using gel electrophoresis to determine the father of a child, each band of the child must match with either the mother or the father. So half must come from the mother and the other half from the father. However, that does not seem to be the case in the picture below, where does the band 6 come from? [image]

Comment: Perhaps the actual father is not included in the tested group?

Comment: Can you confirm or deny that "1" is actually the child's father? An explicity description of what is shown on the gel would be helpful here. Can you think of any explanations other than genetics for unexpected bands on gels?

Comment: This is a very bad question for a scientific site because it contains no explanation of what is being subject to electrophoresis,  not even whether it is DNA, and certainly not how it has been treated. When this question was posted originally this information should have been demanded of the poster. Certainly the question is unanswerable from the information given. It should be closed.